# Mongoose "disconnect is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-an-interactive-command-line-application-with-nodejs) to make a node/mongo application. When I run **addContact**, it seems like the contact saves to the DB but, I get an error saying that the disconnect function is not a function. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and, how to fix it? I'm assume that there's some issue with the scope of the constant, **db**?

code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const assert = require('assert'); 
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 


const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contact-manager');


function toLower(v) {
  return v.toLowerCase();
}

const contactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: { type: String, set: toLower },
  lastname: { type: String, set: toLower },
  phone: { type: String, set: toLower },
  email: { type: String, set: toLower }
});


const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', contactSchema);

const addContact = (contact) => {
  Contact.create(contact, (err) => {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.info('New contact added');
    db.disconnect();
  });
};

const getContact = (name) => {
  const search = new RegExp(name, 'i');
  Contact.find({$or: [{firstname: search }, {lastname: search }]})
  .exec((err, contact) => {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.info(contact);
    console.info(`${contact.length} matches`);
    db.disconnect();
  });
};

module.exports = {  addContact, getContact };
```

code part2:

```
const program = require('commander');

const {addContact, getContact} = require('./logic');

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .description('Contact management system');

program
  .command('addContact <firstame> <lastname> <phone> <email>')
  .alias('a')
  .description('Add a contact')
  .action((firstname, lastname, phone, email) => {
    addContact({firstname, lastname, phone, email});
  });

program
  .command('getContact <name>')
  .alias('r')
  .description('Get contact')
  .action(name => getContact(name));

program.parse(process.argv);
```

error:

```
New contact added
/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: db.disconnect is not a function
    at Contact.create (/Users/user/contact-manager/logic.js:33:8)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3913:16)
    at parallel (/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2077:12)
    at /Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:35:9
    at /Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/async/internal/once.js:12:16
    at iteratorCallback (/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/async/eachOf.js:52:13)
    at /Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/async/internal/onlyOnce.js:12:16
    at /Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/async/internal/parallel.js:32:13
    at apply (/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/lodash/_apply.js:15:25)
    at /Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/lodash/_overRest.js:32:12
    at callbackWrapper (/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:2046:11)
    at /Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3913:16
    at model.$__save.error (/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:342:7)
    at /Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/kareem/index.js:297:21
    at next (/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/kareem/index.js:209:27)
    at Kareem.execPost (/Users/user/contact-manager/node_modules/kareem/index.js:217:3)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mongoose.connect` does not return a value, as far as I can tell from looking at the code given in the [getting started guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/). If you want to close the database connection, you need to call the `close` method on `mongoose.connection` which is written to when you open a connection with `mongoose.connect`. The simplest way to do this is to move your `mongoose.connect` to its own line:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contact-manager');
const db = mongoose.connection;
```

Then just replace your calls to `db.disconnect()` with calls to `db.close()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try letting mongoose handle the connection closure using `mongoose.connection.close()`